# autofac mvc3 property injection

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, autofac

I working on asp.net mvc3 project. I am using autofac for DI.
I have an attribute Say

```
public class MustBeLoggedInAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private IUserContext Context {get;set;}

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
         if (!Context.IsLoggedIn)
             filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/users/logon");  
         base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

}
```

So I need to inject my dependency  IUserContext to this attribute.
How would I achive it. I found codes here and there on actionfiterprovider,
but couldnt find anything complete.

Help will be appreciated.

Regards

Parminder

Comment: The `AuthorizeAttribute` does what you want to do and there is no place for `Autofac` to inject properties in attribute creation process.

Comment: Eranga - AuthorizeAttribute is fine for basic authorization, but falls over after anything basic.

Comment: you guys are not getting the point. I am asking about proprty injection and that can be used for any other purpose. codes here are just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Alex Meyer-Gleaves' write-up on the Autofac wiki: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Mvc3Integration#Filter_Attribute_Property_Injection

You need to call the `RegisterFilterProvider()` extension method:

```
using Autofac.Integration.Mvc;

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
```

This will inject properties into filter attributes as required (as far as I can tell, you don't need to register the attribute types with Autofac for this to work.)

Hope this helps,

Nick

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thanks for the reply. I cant find builder.RegisterControllers and builder.RegisterFilterProvider methods given in this example. Can you suggest where could be the problem.

Comment: Fantastic Nicholas, I forgot to include using Autofac.Integration.Mvc; Thanks mate.